Ok API: PERMISSION_DENIED
ok = OkApi(access_token='',
           application_key='',
           application_secret_key='')

upload = Upload(ok)
upload_response = upload.video(video='ыыыы.mp4', file_name='video', attachment_type='MOVIE', gid='70000032142928')
response = ok.video.update(vid=upload_response['video_id'])
print(response)
print(response.text)

выводит:
<Response [200]>
{"error_code":10,"error_msg":"PERMISSION_DENIED : Key: error.movie.permissionDenied","error_data":null}

Пытаюсь загрузить видео на сервер одноклассников. Пишет error.movie.permissionDenied, но права video content у меня подключены.

Ответ ищите прежде всего там, где взяли информацию по использованию этого API. Данный кусок кода слишком неинформативен чтоб можно было понять суть. Вам отвечают: нет разрешения. Значит, нет его. Значит, неправильно что-то подаётся на вход.
